# I need close and open new browser in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a simple test:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    lib.startApp(constants.ENVIRONMENT, browser);//get url
    loginPageLoc.loginAs(constants.ADMIN_LOGIN,constants.ADMIN_PASSWORD, 
browser);// log in
    browser.driver.sleep(5000); //wait
});

afterEach(function() {
    browser.restart(); //or browser.close()
});

it('Test1' , async() => {
lib.waitUntilClickable(adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers, browser);
    adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers.click();
expect(element(by.css('.common-popup')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
});
it('Test2' , async() => {
lib.waitUntilClickable(adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers, browser);
    adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers.click();
expect(element(by.css('.common-popup')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
});
```

The first iteration looks fine, but after `.restart()` I get:

> Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you
>   call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used. NoSuchSessionError:
>   This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call
>   WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

If I use `.close()` I get:

> Failed: invalid session id

But if I change `Test2` on simple `console.log('case 1');` it looks fine.

Please explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your functions as `async` but are not awaiting the any actions within. If you are not setting your `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` to false in your config then you will see unexpected behavior throughout your test when declaring async functions. This async behavior is likely the cause of your issue so I would ensure `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER:false` and ensure your awaiting your actions in each function.

The reason your test passes if you change the second test to just be console.log() is because you are not interacting with the browser and therefore the selenium session ID is not required. Every time the browser is closed the selenium session id will be destroyed and a new one created when a new browser window is launched.

Also you should be aware that [there is a config setting](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ed955e56a839d7f69da43acb6755763220d3681d/lib/config.ts#L531) you can enable so you do not need to do it manually in your test.

**Update:** Adding code examples of what I have described:

**Note: If you have a lot of code already developed it will take serious effort to convert your framework to Async/await syntax.** For a quicker solution you could try removing the async keywords from your it blocks

Add these to your config

```
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER:false,
restartBrowserBetweenTests:true
```

and change you spec to

```
beforeEach(async function () {
    await lib.startApp(constants.ENVIRONMENT, browser);//get url
    await loginPageLoc.loginAs(constants.ADMIN_LOGIN, constants.ADMIN_PASSWORD,
        browser);// log in
    await browser.driver.sleep(5000); //wait
});

it('Test1', async () => {
    await lib.waitUntilClickable(adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers, browser);
    await adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers.click();
    expect(await element(by.css('.common-popup')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
});
it('Test2', async () => {
    await lib.waitUntilClickable(adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers, browser);
    await adminManagersPage.ButtonManagers.click();
    expect(await element(by.css('.common-popup')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: thanks for explanation! I've done as you adviced, but now i get error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, [type=email]).

Comment: @ArtemKrynychyi Are you sure that locator is correct? You appear to be missing the quotes around the 'email'?

Comment: yes, because when i start old version of test, it looks well

Comment: @Artem Is there any chance your script is failing before that element interaction by your script the original way? Could you try adding some quotes around the email part of that locator, I can't see how that locator would work without the quotes but could be mistaken

Comment: I've figured out why it hasn't worked before. I used function LoginAs which wasn't async. Now i've fixed that and it looks well.  Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a relevant configuration option:

// If true, protractor will restart the browser between each test.

```
restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
```

Add the above in your `config` to restart browser between your tests.

Hope it helps you.